# Entity Framework for over 1000 tables and Class Library for over 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, erp

Our have a ERP project. There are over 1000 tables in this project and there are more than 10 class library in solution. The project is opening very slowly. Maybe 4 - 5 minute. An then if I run the project it is working too late. Very simple queries last 8 - 40 seconds.

```
select * from VeicleColors
```

In this table there are 50 row. But 8 seconds.

What are your suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How much time does it take if you directly execute `select * from VeicleColors` in SQL server? The reason for asking being, I have faced similar issue and it was due to low RAM/disk space in my machine as I had too many applications and browsers running.

Comment: If i use t-sql or stored procedure in the project i have very performance. But, the whole project is written in EF.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the old question, it might be helpful for others having the same issue.

All ERP modules do not use all tables, therefore, it is important to group related table by modules. There will be certain tables (organization structure, user and preferences tables, masters) that are used across modules. Analyze the tables and usage and then:

- Break the EF model into smaller models with tables from related module in one model.
- Try to keep number of tables per model less than 250 (approximately)
- Keep common tables in one or more separate models. You can reference common model in other classes.
- You can use frequently used common tables in other models (plan your namespaces), but restrict table update operations to one base model only.